# PHP (int) / braces mathematically wrong - Possible Bug?

Tags: php, math

Me and my colleges were discussing the following problem, and although we came up with some theories we are still seeing it very odd...

```
<?php

echo (int) ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);

?>
```

outputs **7**

whilst

```
<?php

echo (int) (0.1 + 0.7) * 10;

?>
```

outputs **8** (as expected and as would output if you do it with a calculator)

Could the (int) be causing the issue here? Anyone have an idea?

Thanks a lot and Good Day!

Comment: The last one outputs 0 on my machine.

Comment: Answer `8` looks like the least logical thing that could have happened imo.

Comment: Thanks, confirmed as duplicate and the answer in the above is linking to
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast to integer (and related rounding error) occurs at a different point in the formula

```
Calculate 0.1 plus 0.7, multiply by 10 and cast to integer;
```

with the expected rounding error, should result in 7

against

```
Calculate 0.1 plus 0.7, cast to integer, and multiply by 10
```

casting 0.1 + 0.7 (ie 0.8) to integer should give 0, which multiplied by 10 is still 0